# Is there any way to set up a password for my sqlite3 database in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have made a ToDoList app using Django. It's a rather simple app as I made it while I was just learning Django. I am still a novice programmer. Anyways, for the database I went with Django's default offering SQLite 3. Now my app won't be used by millions of users around the world so a lightweight database works fine but my main concern is that the database is not protected via a password. For production, the app is hosted on PythonAnywhere via their free tier service and they support SQLite3 for free. I know using something like Postgres is preferred for production scale use. But the app is only made as a personal project and no one is likely to use it for commercial use so SQLite3 seems fine. Moreover, using Postgres would require a paid account on PythonAnywhere. So, I was wondering if I could do something to set up a password for my db file.

My settings.py file is this:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_user_agents',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'ToDo.apps.TodoConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_user_agents.middleware.UserAgentMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Django_ToDo_App.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Django_ToDo_App.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "todo-home"
USER_AGENTS_CACHE = 'default'
LOGIN_URL = "login"

EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.getenv("TODO_EMAIL_USER")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.getenv("TODO_EMAIL_PASSWORD")
```

It'd be absolutely helpful if someone could suggest me something that could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, sqlite is very lightweight and minimal and as such doesn't support user control.  You would need something like MySQL instead.  You would have to manage it in your actual view by creating a new credentials table.